# Incoming traffic while on public network

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm developing a web app and I need to be able to get incoming traffic from 3rd party services I use. This is a classic webhooks situation: I send a request with a return address and receive the response (via HTTP) some time later to the given address.

The simple solution would be to provide my external IP address and forward the incoming traffic from the router to my machine. However, I'm working in a large office and I cannot control the router configuration. I'm looking for a different way to achieve that.

I do have servers online. I can have a daemon running on one of those servers, which will handle the incoming traffic. I can run a parallel daemon on my machine, which will keep an open connection with the remote daemon (over ssh preferred) and when an inbound traffic is received by the remote, it will send it to the local, which will send it to the correct port on my machine, as if it was received in the natural way.

Is there any ready-made solution for that?

PS. I'm on OS X and my server is Ubuntu.

Thanks,
zvikico

Comment: The simple solution is to talk to the network administrator to see if they can provide you access to the third party services you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for!  There's a cool project called [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) which does just that: expose your local web server through a mediator server using an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off just retrieving the messages in one connection, not making an outbound that will cause the foreign system to initiate an inbound connection. Adding a third server for the daemon you mentioned simply increases the complexity and makes it more likely to break.

Comment: I didn’t really get your answer. Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I need to be able to receive a message on my machine from a remote service. I don't know when the service will fire the message. Since it's a 3rd party I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the machine in your local network and some remote machine you could use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html)